# Terminated action

Tags: vocabulary

Given crack found on specific area and so a recurrent inspection which has to be done at that area would no longer be required, is it right to say:
" the recurrent inspection at defective area is terminated..."

Comment: The use of "terminated" is reasonable.  The rest of the sentence needs fixing for missing articles, and I'd probably use "has been terminated".  But this is becoming a rewording not an answer

Comment: *The recurr**ing** inspection**s** ha**ve** been **stopped*** would probably be better. Using *terminated* here sounds a bit officialese… and maybe even a trifle violent.

Comment: This statement has a number of issues. 1. It sounds like the recurrent inspection is not required *because* crack was found. 2. It is not clear whether "crack" refers to a physical crack or to the drug. 3. The statement is in something like "headlinese" where some articles and verbs have been omitted. This has made the meaning of yous statement unclear.

Comment: "Terminated" means "stopped." It might be the right word if that's the meaning you want. But if future scheduled inspections will still happen, then "canceled" or "skipped" might be better. Please edit to tell more about what you need.

Answer (score 1):

"Terminated" is fine here.

It should be "THE defective area", not just "defective area".

"Defective" is a very odd word to use here. "Defective" means that there is something wrong with the object. Like if a toaster doesn't turn your bread warm and brown, you could say, "The toaster is defective." But what is defective about the "area"? If in context you have said that the building is in danger of collapsing or some such, okay. But if you simply mean that it is a place where drugs are traded, we don't use the word "defective" for that.

In practice, a fluent speaker would be more likely to say something like, "The regular scheduled inspections at the suspicious area have been stopped." "Recurrent" and "terminated" are rather formal words. You might use them in a formal report intended to sound pretentious, but not in normal conversation.

Oh, and we would probably say "recurring" rather than "recurrent". "Recurrent" is usually used for events outside of our control, like "recurrent storms" or "recurrent attacks by the barbarians". We rarely refer to our own actions as "recurrent".